# I want to read the config file

Tags: node.js

I've tried many solutions on the Internet, but it's not working, reading the config.ini file in node.js.
I'm not using json. 
Below  I've tried

```
//node.js
import {conf} from '../config_phpjs.ini';

or

import conf from '../config_phpjs.ini';

or

var conf = require('../config_phpjs.ini');


const k = conf. (but not 


//config
    [coordinate parameter] 
      ppm        = '3';     
      tipWid     = '256';
```

[Error - 오후 4:08:49] Request textDocument/completion failed.
Message: Request textDocument/completion failed with message: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
Code: -32603

and  net cosole

SCRIPT1086: SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected here

Comment: Can you please also provide the content of your config.ini file

Comment: Calling from php and python in the same format. That's the end of the config.ini content. I just want to get it out of js and use the fixed price.

Comment: Try [ini](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini) package

Comment: maybe  my code start  index.html  on ms edge and  So, import is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ini](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ini) package for parsing ini-files:

```sh
npm i -S ini
```

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ini = require('ini');

const config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('../config_phpjs.ini', 'utf-8'));
```

Comment: I get the same error    SCRIPT1086: SCRIPT1086: Module import or export statement unexpected here

Comment: I trying on the visual studio code and using xampp server